# R shiny main panel display in wrong place

Tags: r, shiny

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Slider App"),
  sidebarLayout(
    h1("Move the slider!"),
    sliderInput(inputId = "n", label = "Sample size", 
                min = 10, max = 1000, value = 30) 
    ),
  mainPanel(
    h3('Illustrating outputs'),
    h4('mean of random normal sample'),
    textOutput(outputId = "output_mean" ),
    h4('variance of random normal sample'),
    textOutput(outputId = "output_var"),
    h4('histogram of random normal sample'),
    plotOutput(outputId = "output_hist") 
    )
) 


server <- function(input, output) {
  output$output_hist <- renderPlot({
    set.seed(1221)
    sample <- rnorm(input$n)
    hist(sample) 
    })
  output$output_mean <- renderText({
    set.seed(1221)
    sample <- rnorm(input$n)
    mean(sample) 
  })
  output$output_var <- renderText({
    set.seed(1221)
    sample <- rnorm(input$n)
    var(sample) 
  })
} 

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I am a new user of R shiny. I wrote a simple code as above, and found out that my main panel are not on the right side of sidebarLayout. I do not know what leads to this and what should I do if I want to move it to the right side of sidebarLayout.

Comment: Any feedback for me?

Comment: Thank you Mike. It works well.

Comment: Could you accept and maybe upvote the answer then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just forgot to include the necessary `sidebarPanel`, so you only have one panel, thus everything in your `fluidPage` is in one column.

You need to add that `sidebarPanel` so that your `ui` code looks like this:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Slider App"),
  sidebarPanel(
    sidebarLayout(
      h1("Move the slider!"),
      sliderInput(inputId = "n", label = "Sample size", 
                  min = 10, max = 1000, value = 30) 
    )
  ),
  mainPanel(
    h3('Illustrating outputs'),
    h4('mean of random normal sample'),
    textOutput(outputId = "output_mean" ),
    h4('variance of random normal sample'),
    textOutput(outputId = "output_var"),
    h4('histogram of random normal sample'),
    plotOutput(outputId = "output_hist") 
  )
)
```

Comment: This is an excellent solution